# display inline block not making divs horizontals

Tags: javascript, html, css

- how to make two divs horizontal
- I gave display: inline-block but not successful
- providing my code below
- an yo tell me how to fix it

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGezoo

```
  <div class ="name-list" >
    <input type="button" value="+New"><br>
    <div class='gettingValues' style='border:1px solid #000;'> getting form values
      <input data-name="edit" type="button" value="Edit" name="editHistory">
      <input data-name="delete" type="button" name="deleteHistory" value="Delete">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class ="contact-details">
    <p>ADD OR EDIT CONTACT (FULL NAME)</p>
    <form id="localStorageTest" method="post" action="">
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="stored" value="" /><br>

      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="stored" value="" /><br>

      <label>Message:</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" class="stored"></textarea><br>

      <input type="submit" class="demo-button" value="Submit" />
      <button type="reset" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: name-list and contact-details

Comment: @Omarjmh, that doesn't seem to work in firefox

Comment: You can try `display: table-cell;`.

Comment: @Omarjmh display: inline not working...do you know why

Comment: @ConnorsFan hey display:table-cell; is working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZPJdg

Comment: Nice catch! Mozilla doesn’t support inline-block
use this for ff: `display:-moz-inline-stack;`

Comment: @Omarjmh can you update in codepen...since its not working

Comment: this seems to work for me: http://codepen.io/omarjmh/pen/aNLRvR

Comment: @Omarjmh i am seeing in chrome...not working but this table-cell working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZPJdg

Comment: go with table-cell, its hacky, but works....for now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following style allows to display divs side by side in all browsers:

```
display: table-cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

"display: inline-block" have `margin-right: 4px`. You should css `margin-right: -4px`

```
.name-list {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

.contact-details {
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues prevent your inline-block divs from sitting side by side.

## Borders

Borders add to the size of your element by default! (GOTHCA!) so in reality your elements are (70% + 2px + 30% + 2px) or (100% + 4px) of your total space! Naturally that won't fit on one line.

This can be fixed by using css box-sizing!

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

or the calc function!

```
calc(70% - 2px) and calc(30% - 2px)
```

## Text Gaps

The second issue is that inline elements can have gaps between them, because inline-block is modeled after text, gaps between the elements in the html create a gap between elements on the page.

This can be fixed by setting the font-size!

```
font-size: 0px;
```

But don't forget to set it back after!

```
font-size: initial;
```

Or you can remove the line break between your elements!

```
<div>
</div><div>
</div>
```

Comment: @texi-rv While you already have a solution this will help you understand why inline-block wasn't working.